# What to replace mysql_result with for MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql

what to replace `mysql_result` with?

im watching a tutorial now but it was made in 2011 so it is not working now.
Here is the situation, I will be very grateful if you tell me what to replace mysql_result with here, and what to put in the parenthesis

```
function update_count() {
    global $link;
    $query  = "SELECT `count`, FROM `hits_count`";
    if($query_run = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        $count = mysql_result($query_run, 0, 'count');
        $count_inc = $count + 1;
        echo $count;
    } 
}
update_count();
```

Comment: Can you explain your question a little bit more?

Comment: You can't use mysql_result on mysql-objects, look att Rocket Hazmats answer. (It should be mysqli_result)

Comment: I completely see what is being asked.  I don't see the big deal.

Answer (score 9):

[`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/mysqli_query) returns you a [`mysqli_result` object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php).  From there, you can get the value you want.

```
if($query_run = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    // This gets you one row at a time, use a while if there are multiple rows
    // while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)){}
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
    $count = $row['count'];
    // Do whatever with $count
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To support a tadman's concise answer with a proof-code

Unlike mysqli, [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) has a long sought mysql_result equivalent:

```
function update_count() {
    global $link;
    $query  = "SELECT `count` FROM `hits_count`";
    $stmt = $link->prepare($query);
    $stmp->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchColumn();
}
echo update_count();
```

Anyone who says that mysqli is no worse than PDO, have to try to bind an array into `IN()` statement using prepared statements first.

Comment: PDO is a lot cleaner and easier to audit than `mysqli`. The only reason I can think to use `mysqli` is if your system is run by a tyrant that hasn't installed PDO.

Answer (score 1):

According to [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php) `mysql_result()` is deprecated since PHP 5.5.0.

So, You should use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) or another method from [`mysqli_result::*` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
function update_count() {
    global $link;
    $query  = "SELECT `count` FROM `hits_count` ;";
    if(($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) && $result->num_rows >= 1) {
        $count = 0 ;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          $count+= $row['count'] ;
        }
        echo $count;
    } 
}
```

Generally would be better to pass that link into the function:

```
function update_count($link) {
    $query  = "SELECT `count` FROM `hits_count` ;";
    if(($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) && $result->num_rows >= 1) {
        $count = 0 ;
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
          $count+= $row['count'] ;
        }
        echo $count;
    }
}
```

Comment: `global $link` is poor practice and takes up additional resources. You should pass it into the function.

Comment: please incorporate failure checking...

Comment: +1 for error check...

Comment: @lhsan Well, thank you. I just posted the original answer before accurate checking, thats true, yeah.